# Is there a way to get administrative access from Windows Subsystem Linux files to Windows files correctly?

Tags: administrator, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Is there a way to access Windows file with administrative rights using WSL?

```
sudo vi /mnt/c/Users/a/admin/file.txt
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I wrote a script that makes this easy: https://github.com/Chronial/wsl-sudo. Using it, you can just run `wudo vi /mnt/c/Users/a/admin/file.txt`. It behaves just like normal sudo, but gives you windows admin rights instead of unix admin rights.

If all you need is a shell with admin privileges, you can just run `powershell.exe Start-Process -Verb runas -FilePath wsl`.

Comment: wudo :-D :-D :-D

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a way to access Windows file with administrative rights using WSL?

Yes;  All that is required in order to do so is to have elevated the command prompt that launched the WSL instance.

> A Bash session with Windows admin privileges may access cd
>   /mnt/c/Users/Administrator while a Bash session without admin
>   privileges would see a "Permission Denied" error.

Microsoft describes the permissions within a WSL instance as the following:

> [image]

Source: [User Accounts and Permissions for Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/user-support)